# Confusing example of usage of was/were

Tags: grammar, grammar-myths

I am just a beginner in English and want to know why is *"were"* used in the first sentence:

> *The least proportion of men **were** detained.*
>
> *The number of men in the party **was** high.*

Number (in sentence 1) and proportion (in sentence 2) both are singular. So why are we using "*were"* in the first sentence but was is used in the second?

Comment: @Englishmonger Please don't ask people to accept your answer. If they feel it is helpful they will do so. Please see [Answers and comments that tell the asker to accept the answer you've given](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/answers-and-comments-that-tell-the-asker-to-accept-the-answer-youve-given) You are pressurizing OP.

Comment: @SudhirSharma Just so you know if you don't already: [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the first generation of computers were or was invented?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147031/the-first-generation-of-computers-were-or-was-invented)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The least proportion of men**  refers to people which is plural so the verb **were** was used
>
> **The number of men** refers to the number which is considered singular and the verb **was** was used because the  number increases or decreases.

Similarly, a number of people is  plural and the number of people is singular

Comment: The author of a post gets notified when an answer is posted to their question. There is no need to tell them in comments to look at, upvote, or accept your answer. In fact, the community frowns on those sorts of comments. See [Answers and comments that tell the asker to accept the answer you've given](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/answers-and-comments-that-tell-the-asker-to-accept-the-answer-youve-given) for more detail.

Comment: @ColleenV - Because this question was asked a mere hour ago, I would go one step further, and encourage the OP to **unaccept** this answer for the time being. Such an action could result in better or more comprehensive answers being added.

Comment: @Sudhir  Sharma. please  down vote my answer and unaccept it .You may  get a better answer than mine

Comment: @Englishmonger - There is no need to request a downvote either. Let's learn a lesson but not be overly contrite.  :-)

Comment: We ask authors to wait a little while before accepting an answer so that their post gets more attention. Ideally every question here should have more than one answer because different perspectives can help learners understand a concept better than just one way of explaining it. It doesn’t necessarily mean that one answer is better or more correct.